# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'prj_oxbir.permissions' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, laravel

Permissions file does exist on the folder though. Why this error is showing.

> In Connection.php line 647:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'prj_oxbir.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from
>   `permissions`)
>
> In Connection.php line 319:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'prj_oxbir.permissions' doesn't exist

createrolestable.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['role_id' , 'permission_id']);
        });

        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['role_id' , 'user_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

Comment: that error is about a missing database table, not a file in a folder ... use the stack trace to find what is trying to query that `permissions` table ... as you haven't ran that migration yet

Comment: what do I do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure table `permissions` exist in the database.

Secondly, create a separate migrations for `permissions` table.

hope this helps.